# Regex not removing invalid chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a textfield for hex colors on the `keyup` event using regex, like this:

```
if (/[^0-9A-Fa-f]$/i.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9A-Fa-f]$/g, '');
```

It works when I enter chars, but when I paste in something that has an invalid char in it (like 'return', 'hexTextField'), it doesn't remove the invalid chars.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

#### JSFiddle

```js
document.getElementById('hexTextField').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '');
  // If not 'if statement', when press special chars (ex arrows), won't work.
  if (/[^0-9A-Fa-f]$/i.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9A-Fa-f]$/g, '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="hexTextField" spellcheck="false" maxlength="6">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well that's because you have your regexes scoped to "$" end of string, which means in case when you paste your "return" -> it's going to check only last char in it.

So just remove "$" from your last assignment in if()

Answer (score 0):

You can further simplify it to:

```js
document.getElementById('hexTextField').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\W/g, '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="hexTextField" spellcheck="false" maxlength="6">
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want from a-z, I want from a-f. This is hex color format